# Emmet Vim wrap a specific tag around

Tags: html, vim, emmet, abbreviation

This is very basic but I just could not find an easier way of doing it.

I have an html file and I want to wrap `<strong></strong>` around some part.

So, I go to visual mode. Select the text. Do `Control Y - ,`. It asks for Tag. I enter strong and it wraps the tags as expected.

But this is way too long for vim IMHO.

Is not there a quicker/ easier way to get this done? May be an abbreviation attached to a keystroke?

So, I select the text in visual mode, press a key and there --- `<strong> </strong>` appear around it?

Comment: Why don't you ask about that on emmet's issue tracker?

Comment: I think this might help: http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `surround` plugin it's select the text in visual mode, press `S<`, tag name, `<cr>`.

Or `ys`, motion or text object, `<`, tag name, `<cr>`.

`<` can be replaced by `t`, attributes can be appended to the tag name, and `<cr>` can be replaced by `>`.